# Matlab GUI - How to send a dynamically formatted string via serial?

Tags: matlab, serial-port, slider, matlab-guide, popupmenu

I'm trying to send a string, composed of characters and a decimal number, via serial using fprintf. The format of the string I'd like to send is the following:

> Roll,Cons,Kp,3.12

- The first and the second words depend on the state (or better value) of a popup menu.
- The number to send is the value of a **slider** called *pidKpSlider* that is part of **GUI** shown below.

[image]

**The callback code of the slider:**

```
function pidKpSliderCallBack(src,eventData)
   set(pidKpVal,'String',get(pidKpSlider,'Value'));
   fprintf(xbee,'%s,%s,%s,%.2f','Roll','Cons','Kp',get(pidKpSlider,'Value')); 
end
```

As I move the slider, ***the value in the text box is updated correctly*** but the string isn't sent.
The callback code returns the following error.

```
Connection established. Rock & Roll!
You are in PID mode 
Error using serial/fprintf (line 115)
Too many input arguments.

Error in ControlBoard1_35/pidKpSliderCallBack (line 402)
       fprintf(xbee,'%s,%s,%s,%.2f','Roll','Cons','Kp',get(pidKpSlider,'Value'));
```

How can I correctly send the string?

### **Solution**

Declare 2 global string functions

```
global pidStrategy;
global pidModeStrategy;

% Initialize them to U (which stands for unset)
pidStrategy = 'U';
pidModeStrategy = 'U';
```

*PopMenus*

```
pidPopup = uicontrol('Style','popupmenu','Position', [370 325 150 30],... 
    'String','Select|Roll|Pitch|Yaw|Altitude','visible','off', ...
    'Parent',hTabs(4), 'Callback',@pidPopupCallback);

pidModePopup = uicontrol('Style','popupmenu','Position', [370 280 150 30],... 
    'String','Select|Conservative|Aggressive','visible','off', ...
    'Parent',hTabs(4), 'Callback',@pidModePopupCallback);
```

*PopMenu callback functions*

```
%# drop-down pid menu callback
function pidPopupCallback(src,~)
    %# update plot color
    val = get(src,'Value');

    % Roll Pid Selected
    if val == 1
       pidStrategy = 'U';
       %disp('Unset');
    end

    % Roll Pid Selected
    if val == 2
       pidStrategy = 'Rol';
       %disp('Rol');
    end

    % Pitch Pid Selected
    if val == 3
       pidStrategy = 'Pit';  
       %disp('Pit');            
    end

    % Yaw Pid Selected
    if val == 4
       pidStrategy = 'Yaw';
       %disp('Yaw');
    end

    % Altitude Pid Selected
    if val == 5
       pidStrategy = 'Alt';
       %disp('Alt');
    end
end

%# drop-down pid Mode menu callback
function pidModePopupCallback(src,~)
    %# update plot color
    val = get(src,'Value');
    % Roll Pid Selected
    if val == 1
       pidModeStrategy = 'U';
       %disp('Unset');
    end

    % Conservative Mode Selected
    if val == 2
       pidModeStrategy = 'Cons';
       %disp('Con');
    end

    % Aggressive Mode Selected
    if val == 3
       pidModeStrategy = 'Agg'; 
       %disp('Agg');
    end
end
```

*Slider Code:*

```
% Text Box to show the value of the slider
pidKpVal = uicontrol('Style','text', 'String','AS', ...
    'Position', [484 56 40 25],'Visible','off',...
    'Parent',hTabs(4), 'FontSize',13,'FontWeight','normal');

%Slider and listener
pidKpSlider = uicontrol('Style','slider','Visible','off',...
'min',0,'max',2,'Callback',@(s,e) disp('KpSlider'),...
'SliderStep',[0.01 0.10],'Position', [140 185 350 20]);
KpListener = addlistener(pidKpSlider,'Value','PostSet',@pidKpSliderCallBack);
```

*Slider Callback*

```
function pidKpSliderCallBack(src,eventData)
   set(pidKpVal,'String',get(pidKpSlider,'Value')); 
   % send value only if the popup menu are correctly set
   if ~strcmp(pidStrategy,'U') && ~strcmp(pidModeStrategy,'U')
   strindToSend = [pidStrategy,',',pidModeStrategy,',Kp,',num2str(get(pidKpSlider,'Value'))]
   fprintf(xbee,'%s',strindToSend,'sync'); 
   end
end
```

The result is exactly what I was looking for! The program sends via serial decimal values corresponding to the cursor's position only if the options in the popmenus are set.

Comment: Could it be because you forgot a single quote after `Cons`?
fprintf(xbee,'%s,%s,%s,%.2f','Roll','Cons','Kp',get(pidKpSlider,'Value'),'sync')

Comment: Sorry it was a copy and paste error.

Comment: Perhaps because you have 4 fields in the format string and give 5 values?

Comment: The mode field doesn't count, if I remove it the error is still the same: `Error using serial/fprintf (line 115)
Too many input arguments.
Error in ControlBoard1_35/pidKpSliderCallBack (line 402)
       fprintf(xbee,'%s,%s,%s,%.2f','Roll','Cons','Kp',get(pidKpSlider,'Value'));`

Comment: Ah! The issue is not with `fprintf` but with `get(pidKpSlider,'Value')`. Is this part of a GUI? What is the callback code for the slider object?

Comment: Yes it is. Here is the code of the callback function:
`function pidKpSliderCallBack(src,eventData)
   set(pidKpVal,'String',get(pidKpSlider,'Value'));
   fprintf(xbee,'%s,%s,%s,%.2f','Roll','Cons','Kp',get(pidKpSlider,'Value')); 
end`

Comment: If `get(pidKpSlider,'Value')` is a number, as I suspect, you need to convert it to a string in `set(pidKpVal,'String',num2str(get(pidKpSlider,'Value')));`

Comment: If I remove the fprintf command from the Callback function it works in both cases (with and without the conversion). Unfortunatly I get same error as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`fprintf (serial)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/serial.fprintf.html), you can only send one command, so you need to concatenate all your data into one command:

```
fprintf(xbee,'Roll,Cons,Kp,%.2f',get(pidKpSlider,'Value'),'sync');
```

You can't have multiple inputs, as you wrote your code.

Comment: Ok that's great! We're close. Agg,Cons and Kp are dynamics, I should probably first create the string and then send it.

Comment: I used this example from the doc: `fprintf(s,['ch:%d scale:%d'],[1 20e-3],'sync');`

Comment: Finally, I created the string as a function of the value of the popup menus and the cursors, then I sent it via serial.

Comment: What about a binary protocol instead of a strings-based one? This other option is less prone to error, will result in shorter transmissions (and more compact code), and will better lend itself to future enhancements. Is there any Matlab functions to create a binary structured communications?